# Subquery with TOP 1 returns more than one row in Oracle NetSuite

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

Subquery returnes more than one row despite using TOP 1.

I have worked with MS SQL for most of my life in which I am sure the following code would work but in Oracle (NetSuite) it does not.

I am trying to join rows from table TRANSACTIONS with rows from table SYSTEM_NOTES using a TRANSACTION_ID column in the way that for every row in TRANSACTIONS only one row from SYSTEM_NOTES should be returned.

The SYSTEM_NOTES table may have none, one or multiple rows with a TRANSACTION_ID matching the one from the TRANSACTION table.

The query should return only the latest row (determined based on the DATE_CREATED column in the SYSTEM_NOTES table).

```
SELECT 
    SS.NAME AS "ENTITY NAME", 
    TL.TRANSACTION_ID AS "TRANSACTION INTERNAL ID", 
    WF.VALUE_NEW AS "APPROVED BY",
    WF.DATE_CREATED AS "APPROVED DATE",
    TL.AMOUNT AS "AMOUNT (entity currency)",
    (CASE WHEN TL.AMOUNT_FOREIGN IS NULL THEN TL.AMOUNT ELSE TL.AMOUNT_FOREIGN END) AS "AMOUNT (original currency)",
    CY.SYMBOL AS "CURRENCY CODE"
FROM TRANSACTIONS TS
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS AC ON TL.ACCOUNT_ID  = AC.ACCOUNT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTING_PERIODS AP ON TS.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_ID = AP.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 

/* The following part for some entries returns more than one row despite using TOP 1 */

(SELECT TOP 1 SN.TRANSACTION_ID, SN.VALUE_NEW, SN.DATE_CREATED FROM SYSTEM_NOTES SN WHERE SN.STANDARD_FIELD = 'NEXTAPPROVER' AND SN.VALUE_NEW IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY SN.DATE_CREATED DESC) 
WF ON WF.TRANSACTION_ID = TS.TRANSACTION_ID
/* End of the faulty part */

WHERE TL.AMOUNT IS NOT NULL AND TL.AMOUNT <> 0
AND TS.IS_NON_POSTING = N'No'
AND (AP.QUARTER = N'No' AND AP.YEAR_0 = N'No' AND CAST(AP.STARTING AS DATE) BETWEEN {d '2018-12-01'} AND {d '2018-12-01'})
```

When I run the subquery alone for one transaction id I get only 1 row as expected (there are three entries with that ID in the SYSTEM_NOTES table).

```
SELECT TOP 1 
SN.TRANSACTION_ID, 
SN.VALUE_NEW, SN.DATE_CREATED FROM SYSTEM_NOTES SN WHERE SN.STANDARD_FIELD = 'NEXTAPPROVER' AND SN.VALUE_NEW IS NOT NULL AND SN.TRANSACTION_ID = 171954
    ORDER BY SN.DATE_CREATED DESC
```

I have also tried the the following code but the row_number() part does not seem to work in my system.

```
SELECT SN.TRANSACTION_ID, SN.VALUE_NEW, SN.DATE_CREATED,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SN.DATE_CREATED DESC ) AS ROW_NUM
 FROM SYSTEM_NOTES SN 
WHERE SN.STANDARD_FIELD = 'NEXTAPPROVER' AND SN.VALUE_NEW IS NOT NULL
AND SN.TRANSACTION_ID = 171954
```

Comment: I'm not aware that Oracle supports `SELECT TOP`, so I'm surprised this works at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `rownum` instead of `TOP`.

Syntax:

```
 select * from dual where /*conditions*/ and rownum = 1
```

I made an example for you:

- with `rownum` :

[Example - rownum = 1](https://rextester.com/UGCJE11094)

- with `row_number` :

[Example - row_number()](https://rextester.com/DLLTW53816)